# swift : merge the same processing code by prop type, not by prop name?

Tags: ios, swift

How to merge the same processing code by property type, not by property name?

**Here is the case:**

```
struct GroupA{
    let name: String
    let memberNum: Int
    
    var info: String{
        var result = "\(memberNum) "
        if memberNum > 1{
            result += "members"
        }
        else{
            result += "member"
        }
        return result + " in \(name)"
    }
}
```

- code to merge

```
struct GroupB{
    let title: String
    let peopleCount: Int
    
    var info: String{
        var result = "\(peopleCount) "
        if peopleCount > 1{
            result += "members "
        }
        else{
            result += "member "
        }
        return result + "in \(title)"
    }
    
}
```

**code usage example:**

```
let a = GroupA(name: "haha ", memberNum: 5)

print(a.info)


let b = GroupB(title: "Bull", peopleCount: 6)

print(b.info)
```

#### Here is my solution:

```
struct GroupB{
    let title: String
    let peopleCount: Int
    
    var converted: GroupA{
        GroupA(name: title, memberNum: peopleCount)
    }
}
```

- and usage:

```
let b = GroupB(title: "Bull", peopleCount: 6)

print(b.converted.info)
```

> I think it is a little hard to use pop

**reflection** is an option

---

for the following example:

> I think it is a little tough to use *reflection*

```
struct GroupC{
    let title: String
    let peopleCount: Int
    let leaderName: String
}
```

### Any other better idea?

---

PS：

- to merge

`var info: String{ ... }`

- "processing code" is

" sth ( number) sth (title) sth"

> number in groupA is memberNum, number in groupB is peopleCount

> title is much alike

just a simple demo pattern

Comment: What is "processing code" and what exactly is it you want to merge?

Comment: to merge ` var info: String{`

Comment: "processing code"  is " sth \( number) sth \(title) sth"

Comment: number in groupA is memberNum,  number in groupB is peopleCount.    title is much alike

Comment: a little similar to POP

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting these cryptic comments.

Comment: What is "merge"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you don't want to merge, you want to factorize...

So:

```
struct InfoFormatting {
    static func infos(from text: String, andNumber number: Int) -> String {
        var result = "\(number) "
        if number > 1 {
            result += "number"
        }
        else {
            result += "number"
        }
        return result + " in \(text)"
    }
}
```

I've created `InfoFormatting`, but it could be elsewhere, it depends on your architecture on where it would make more sense.

Then:

```
struct GroupA {
   ...
    var info: String { 
        InfoFormatting.infos(from: name, andNumber: memberNum)
    }
}

struct GroupA {
   ...
    var info: String { 
        InfoFormatting.infos(from: title, andNumber: peopleCount)
    }
}
```

That is the basic factorization.

Now, you could also use instead a protocol:

```
protocol InfoFormatter {
    var infos: String { get }
}

extension InfoFormatter {
   func infos(from text: String, andNumber number: Int) -> String {
        var result = "\(number) "
        if number > 1 {
            result += "number"
        }
        else {
            result += "number"
        }
        return result + " in \(text)"
    }
}
```

And make `GroupA` & `GroupB` compliant with it:

```
struct GroupA: InfoFormatter {
    let name: String
    let memberNum: Int
    
    var info: String {
        infos(from: name, andNumber: memberNum)
    }
}

struct GroupB: InfoFormatter {
    let title: String
    let peopleCount: Int
    
    var info: String {
        infos(from: title, andNumber: peopleCount)
    }
}
```